# Error in OpenCV OCL module

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

I am trying to use surf implementation using OpenCL module in OpenCV. Everything run smoothly, including surf feature detection, but right before ending the program, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000000013F66DEA3 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

The call stack is as follows:

```
Project.exe!std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::_Tidy() Line 1623    C++
Project.exe!std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::~vector<int,std::allocator<int> >() Line 946 C++
Project.exe!cv::ocl::PlatformInfoImpl::~PlatformInfoImpl()  C++
Project.exe!cv::ocl::PlatformInfoImpl::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)   C++
Project.exe!cv::ocl::ContextImpl::~ContextImpl() Line 620   C++
[External Code] 
Project.exe!cv::ocl::ContextImpl::cleanupContext() Line 762 C++
Project.exe!cv::ocl::__Module::~__Module() Line 926 C++
[External Code]
```

Comment: This looks like a stack trace. Do you have an actual error message?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question. I get the following error: Unhandled exception at 0x000000013F66DEA3 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Comment: In this case, without your code, we can not help. You are dereferencing a pointer to a non allocated address.

Comment: I put the entire call stack. This is all from cv::ocl module. I have no error when deleting the ocl::surf object.